# Input type=" time " returning NAN if get hours value only

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input that user able to input the *time*.

I want to get the *hours* only because I will using it on some of my conditions.
But using the code below, I get **NAN** value.
Is there a way to get the *hour* only using `<input type="time">`? **not included** the *minutes*?

*Example 1:
User input => **10:32 am**
get => **10**

*Example 2:
User input => **03:11 pm**
get => **15** //24hrs.

*Require to use **`<input type="time">`**.

Below is my sample code(attempt only).

```js
function showTime(){
  let time = document.getElementById('myTime');
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let getHours = new Date('time').getHours()
  console.log(getHours)
  getHours < 12 ? output.innerText = 'Morning'
  : getHours < 18 ? output.innerText = 'Afternoon'
  : getHours < 24 ? output.innerText = 'Evening'
  : output.innerText = 'Error getting hour!';

}
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkred;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<label>Time In: </label><input id='myTime' type='time'/>
<br><br>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show Hour Only</button>
<br><br>
<span id='output'></span>
```

Comment: just use type="number"

Comment: Already add in the question *Require to use <input type="time">*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date(time)` returns *null* on which you are trying use `getHours()`. You can split the time *value* and get the first element of the array using the `[0]` *index* to get the hours.

**Code Example:**

```js
function showTime(){
  let time = document.getElementById('myTime');
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let getHours = time.value.split(":")[0];
  console.log(getHours);
  getHours < 12 ? output.innerText = 'Morning'
  : getHours < 18 ? output.innerText = 'Afternoon'
  : getHours < 24 ? output.innerText = 'Evening'
  : output.innerText = 'Error getting hour!';
}
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkred;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<label>Time In: </label><input id='myTime' type='time'/>
<br><br>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show Hour Only</button>
<br><br>
<span id='output'></span>
```

Comment: the answer is too complicated and the code is superfluous. op's code is very neat this is simply a semantic error

Comment: and no matter what you pass in `new Date` will never return `null`

Comment: @TachibanaShin, please add workable code snippet in the solution you have provided!

Comment: i added demo to the answer and added 1/1/1

Comment: @TachibanaShin, now check which is clean and which is complex!

Answer (score 1):

Wrong format, you need year, month and second.

```js
function showTime() {
  let time = document.getElementById('myTime').value;
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let now = new Date()
  let getHours = new Date(`${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()}-${now.getDate()} ${time}:00`).getHours();
  output.innerText = getHours < 12 ? 'Morning' : getHours < 18 ? 'Afternoon' : getHours < 24 ? 'Evening' : 'Error getting hour!'
}
```

```html
<label>Time In: </label><input id='myTime' type='time' />
<br><br>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show Hour Only</button>
<br><br>
<span id='output'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

edit line 4 of js to :

```js
let getHours = new Date('1/1/1 '+ time.value).getHours()
```

and it will work

```js
function showTime(){
  let time = document.getElementById('myTime');
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let getHours = new Date('1/1/1 '+ time.value).getHours()
  console.log(getHours)
  getHours < 12 ? output.innerText = 'Morning'
  : getHours < 18 ? output.innerText = 'Afternoon'
  : getHours < 24 ? output.innerText = 'Evening'
  : output.innerText = 'Error getting hour!';

}
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkred;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<label>Time In: </label><input id='myTime' type='time'/>
<br><br>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show Hour Only</button>
<br><br>
<span id='output'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `time.value` still the input value is only time component not complete date so that you are not able to achieve the required output. Here's the working code as you wanted.

Extracting only hours part from the time and then checking is it valid then outputting it.

```js
function showTime() {
  let time = document.getElementById('myTime');
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let hours = parseInt(time.value.substr(0, 2)); 
  console.log(hours);
  if (!isNaN(hours)) {
    output.innerText = hours < 12 ? 'Morning' :
      hours < 18 ? 'Afternoon' :
      hours < 24 ? 'Evening' :
      'Error getting hour!';
  } else {
    output.innerText = 'Invalid input';
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkred;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<label>Time In: </label><input id='myTime' type='time' />
<br><br>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show Hour Only</button>
<br><br>
<span id='output'></span>
```